# Could someone be born mute

Tags: science-based, internal-consistency, diseases

In a story I'm writing, the main character is a mute and I was wondering could someone be either born mute or become mute at a very young age in a medieval setting?

Note: magic does not exist in my story

Comment: Just to be clear, you want something which causes specifically the inability to speak, instead of common [deaf-mute](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deaf-mute)?

Comment: Um... What degree of research did you do into the question of whether people can be born mute?

Comment: Um... yes?

"When I was born I was so surprised I didn't talk for a year and a half."  -Gracie Allen

It kinda comes with territory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's certainly possible.

There are several disorders that could cause a kid to be completely mute. An example is [Alalia/Speech delay](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Speech_delay). A congenital deformation could be a cause for someone unable to produce vocal sounds. So someone who isn't intellectually impaired is still unable to produce any vocal sounds.

Some people with autism never learn to speak at all. But these are usually the more serious cases and are often accompanied by other mental deficiencies that might be undesirable depending on the role this particular character plays in your story.

Then the third option is injury or disease. When knowledge of healthcare and diseases mostly eluded the medieval folks, lots of things went wrong.

[Dysarthria](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dysarthria) for example can be caused by hypoxic brain injury. This could be caused by an umbilical chord wrapped around a baby's neck. (Given how awful the outcomes could be here, just ending up mute could be considered to be lucky given the standards of healthcare back then).

Answer (score 8):

Short answer: yes.

Longer answer: yes, but be aware that congenital and developmental issues that cause muteness often have other serious effects, such as interfering with breathing, or involving a tumour that can go on to kill the affected person.

An injury in infancy or early childhood could cause some suitable traumatic damage that would do the job. There'd be a certain amount of luck involved with not dying from the initial injury or inevitable complications, but it would all be plausible enough.

The simplest thing is just declare it to be so. You're the boss; handwave it in, and don't go into unnecessary detail and it'll be fine.